# Overriding Regexp class =~ operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading, match

I'm solving a Ruby Quiz, to be precise #4. It requires to Monkey Patch the Regexp class and add a build() method to it, that does the following:

```
lucky = Regexp.build(3, 7)
"7" =~ lucky # => true
"13" =~ lucky # => false
"3" =~ lucky # => true
```

I'm pretty much there, Here's what I've got so far...

```
> lucky = Regexp.build(3, 7)
> "7" =~ lucky  => 0 
> "13" =~ lucky => nil 
> "3" =~ lucky  => 0
```

As you can see, my only problem here is that **I'm not returning a true or false**, but 0 and nil instead. 
Could you guys please help me getting an idea of how to override the =~ operator to accomplish this? (If this is the way to go) or let me know what is the right thing to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your code so far?

Comment: https://github.com/jlstr/Regexp.build--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Ruby idiom for turning something into a boolean, `!!`. `nil` and `false` are falsey, negating them yields `true`, which in turn negates to `false`. Any truthy value first gets turned into a `false` and then becomes `true`:

```
>> !!0
=> true
>> !!nil
=> false
```

It's hard to give you more hints without seeing your code, but it seems like putting a `!!` in at the right spot will solve your problem.

Comment: Here's my code:
https://github.com/jlstr/Regexp.build--
One class, and one module. Simple enough...
Hopefully you may be able to give me more hints based on what you see there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using a wrapper and the code you provided, I was able to solve my problem, thanks Michael !

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't think that the exact return value is important to the quiz. The semantics he uses in [quiz 4](http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz4.html) don't match up with the documentation for `=~` in either [ruby 1.8](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_7_330/Regexp/=~) or [ruby 1.9](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/Regexp/=~).

I'd say as long as you're returning a value that's consistant with your version of Ruby then you're fine. In general that'll mean not overriding `=~` at all and just setting up the pattern correctly - which I think was the point of the exercise

Comment: Well, I agree to what you've just said. I think the important part is solved and the return type should be trivial. On the other hand I hope you liked my code. :) thanks Gareth